# How can I make Sublime Text 3 use my $PATH?

Tags: php, shell, sublimetext3, macos-sierra

I have a sublime plugin which executes a script that starts with

```
#!/usr/bin/env php
```

Now, when I execute this script from a terminal it will use the php I have in my `$PATH` (installed by phpbrew) but when the sublime plugin executes the script it will use the `php` binary installed by macOS (Sierra), which is not the same PHP version. (Note that the plugin does not specify which binary to use, it is resolved by `#!/usr/bin/env php` when executing the script).

How can I make Sublime respect my `$PATH` settings?

**Edit:** I changed `#!/usr/bin/env php` to `#!/path/to/my/php/version` in the script that was going to be executed and it works as a work-around for now.

Comment: I assume you are using build. Then from terminal you can choose php path by `which php` and provide it in sublime build and from terminal you can use any php you want to sue

Comment: I'm not using build. What is that?

Comment: From Menu select tool the select build system if you see php  then modify it else clcik new build system. http://sublimetext.info/docs/en/reference/build_systems.html

Comment: Would that really have any effect on command executed by plugins? They're not building anything, it's a linter/fixer.

Comment: Your workaround seems to be a solution rather then a workaround? The shebang you are using indicates to Sublime which executable to use to run the script.

Comment: I'm looking for a solution where `#!/usr/bin/env php` will resolve to the php in my $PATH even when it's executed by Sublime. Basically, Sublime Text 3 doesn't use my $PATH. How do I fix that?

Comment: Ah! Maybe [this](https://github.com/int3h/SublimeFixMacPath) would help :)?

Comment: Yes! Thank you @SB87 , that plugin solved my problem.

Comment: Great! So it is solved then? Added my comment as an answer so the question can be solved & closed :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There appear to be some known problems with Sublime's PATH settings on macOS. There is a plugin for it at Git:

https://github.com/int3h/SublimeFixMacPath

Answer (score 0):

SB87's answer solves the problem for the current beta of Sublime Text 3 (build 3126). However, on April 12 (10 days after SB87's answer) the [development build 3127](https://www.sublimetext.com/3dev) was released, which among other things include:

> OS X: the user's default shell is executed and environmental variables are set in the plugin Python environment

I have not yet tested it so I can't confirm it works, but there it is.